# Reducing length of list with Total and a threshold parameter

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm looking for a way to reduce the length of a huge list with the Total function and a threshold parameter. I would like to avoid the use of For and If (coming from old habits).

Example : 
List that I want to "reduce" :`{1,5,3,8,11,3,4}` with a threshold of `5`.

Output that I want : `{6,11,11,7}`
That means that I use the Total function on the first parts of the list and look if the result of this function is higher than my threshold. If so, I use the result of the Total function and go to the next part of the list.

Another example is `{1,1,1,1,1}` with a threshold of `5`. Result should be `{5}`.

Thanks!

EDIT : it is working but it is pretty slow. Any ideas in order to be faster?

EDIT 2 : the loop stuff (quit simple and not smart)

```
For[i = 1, i < Length[mylist] + 1, i++,
sum = sum + mylist[[i]];
  If[sum > Threshold ,
result = Append[result , sum]; sum = 0;   ];   ];
```

EDIT 3 : I have now a new thing to do.
I have to work now with a 2D list like `{{1,2}{4,9}{1,3}{0,5}{7,3}}`
It is more or less the same idea but the 1st and 2nd part of the list have to be higher than the thresold stuff (both of them).
Example : `If lst[[1]] and lst[[2]] > threshold do the summuation` for each part of the 2D list. I tried to adapt the f2 function from Mr.Wizard for this case but I didn't succeed. If it is easier, I can provide 2 independant lists and work with this input `f3[lst1_,lst2_,thres_]:= 
 Reap[Sow@Fold[If[Element of the lst1 > thr && Element of the lst2, Sow@#; #2, # + #2] &, 0, lst1]][[2, 1]]` for example.

EDIT 4 :
You are right, it is not really clear. But the use of the `Min@# > thr` statement is working perfectly.

Old code (ugly and not smart at all):

```
sumP = 0;
resP = {};
sumU = 0;
resU = {};
For[i = 1, i < Length[list1 + 1, i++,
 sumP = sumP + list1[[i]];
 sumU = sumU + list2[[i]];
 If[sumP > 5 && sumU > 5 ,
  resP = Append[resP, sumP]; sumP = 0;
  resU = Append[resU, sumU]; sumU = 0;
  ];
 ]
```

NEW fast by Mr.Wizard :

```
   f6[lst_, thr_] := 
 Reap[Sow@Fold[If[Min@# > thr  , Sow@#1; #2, #1 + #2] &, 0, lst]][[2, 
   1]]
```

That ~40times faster. Thanks a lot.

```
Thread[{resP, resU}] == f6[Thread[{list1,list2}], 5] True
```

Comment: Please add an example of the input and output needed with the `{x,x}` form.  It is not clear to me what gets added.  You can probably apply the threshold test with `Min@# > thr`.

Comment: Your suggestion Min@# > thr works. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `Fold` for this kind of operation, combined with either linked lists or `Sow` and `Reap` to accumulate results.  `Append` is slow because lists in *Mathematica* are arrays and must be reallocated every time an element is appended.

Starting with:

```
lst = {2, 6, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 0, 7, 4};
```

Here is the linked-list version:

```
Flatten @ Fold[If[Last@# > 5, {#, #2}, {First@#, Last@# + #2}] &, {{}, 0}, lst]
```

> ```
> {8, 8, 7, 7, 11, 4}
> ```

This is what the output looks like before `Flatten`:

> ```
> {{{{{{{}, 8}, 8}, 7}, 7}, 11}, 4}
> ```

---

Here is the method using `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Reap[Sow @ Fold[If[# > 5, Sow@#; #2, # + #2] &, 0, lst]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {8, 8, 7, 7, 11, 4}
> ```

A similar method applied to other problems: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2307/121) [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6654/121)

The `Sow @` on the outside of `Fold` effectively appends the last element of the sequence which would otherwise be dropped by the algorithm.

---

Here are the methods packaged as functions, along with george's for easy comparison:

```
f1[lst_, thr_] := 
  Flatten @ Fold[If[Last@# > thr, {#, #2}, {First@#, Last@# + #2}] &, {{}, 0}, lst]

f2[lst_, thr_] := 
  Reap[Sow@Fold[If[# > thr, Sow@#; #2, # + #2] &, 0, lst]][[2, 1]]

george[t_, thresh_] := Module[{i = 0, s},
  Reap[While[i < Length[t], s = 0; 
     While[++i <= Length[t] && (s += t[[i]]) < thresh]; Sow[s]]][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

Timings:

```
big = RandomInteger[9, 500000];

george[big, 5] // Timing // First
```

> 1.279

```
f1[big, 5] // Timing // First

f2[big, 5] // Timing // First
```

> 0.593
>
> 0.468

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. Unfortunately I have to additional treatement. See my edit for that.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your requirement as:

- if an element in the list is less than the threshold value, add it to the next element in the list;
- repeat this process until the list no longer changes.

So, for the threshold `5` and the input list `{1,5,3,8,11,3,4}` you'ld get

```
{6,3,8,11,3,4}
{6,11,11,3,4}
{6,11,11,7}
```

**EDIT**

I've now tested this solution to your problem ...

Implement the operation by using a replacement rule:

```
myList = {1,5,3,8,11,3,4}
threshold = 5
mylist = mylist //. {a___, b_ /; b < threshold, c_, d___} :> {a, b+c, d}
```

Note the use of `ReplaceRepeated` (symbolification `//.`).

Comment: Oh well thanks a lot! I will test tomorrow and tell you the result. I will have to handle lists of ~500 000 values (mostly composed of 0 or 1) : hope that it will not take forever.

Comment: Well, if your data series are mostly 0s and 1s why didn't you include that information in your question, there may well be a faster way of operating on such series.

Comment: Because the distribution of the values are "random" : that means that I'll have mostly 0 and 1 but also 2,3 or even 4 and so on. I didn't know that was an important info, sorry of that.

Comment: I is working but it is slow. Any suggestion in order to be faster?

Comment: Yeah sure. For the moment, I am using a For loop and an If statement.

Comment: HPM, you should use `RuleDelayed` for replacement rules with name patterns, to correctly localize the symbols.

Comment: And, in this case, probably prefer @george's solution entirely.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: HPM, I much prefer Fold; see my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the obvious approach which is oh 300x faster.. Pretty isn't always best.

```
t = Random[Integer, 10] & /@ Range[2000];
threshold = 4;
Timing[
  i = 0; 
  t0 = Reap[
     While[i < Length[t], s = 0; 
     While[++i <= Length[t] && (s += t[[i]]) < threshold ]; 
     Sow[s]]][[2, 1]]][[1]]
Total[t] == Total[t0]
Timing[ t1 = 
   t //. {a___, b_ /; b < threshold, c_, d___} -> {a, b + c, d} ][[1]]
t1 == t0
```